# Prevent user from creating a request from another page

Tags: authentication, client-server, httprequest, csrf-protection

This is technically a csrf attack but this time I am trying to prevent the requests from the user no matter if they are unintentional or not.

I have a cloud storage service where a user can perform CRUD operations on files. I would like to exclusive limit this functionality to my site. So that they could not say, forge a request via postman or cURL and use the service through those methods.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to tell whether a user takes any given action via a browser or by hand-crafting an identical series of HTTP requests.  What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit, I have a bit of a unique problem. I am trying to create an art service where a server is shared with applications that were not necessarily written by me so they cannot be trusted. I would like to prevent two things : one is an application creating a request impersonating another application , and two a user who is not the application itself impersonating the application. I have mitigated the first problem by embedding a JS object in the application and then freezing it to prevent it from being changed

Comment: but I do not know how to mitigate the second one, since a person can look at the console/reply from the server and easily obtain the object that was passed in, and use it in a fraudulent request to impersonate the application

Comment: It sounds like you actually just want each application to have a private key (or an OAuth-style API key)

Comment: What's wrong with a user impersonating the application? They obviously already have access.

Comment: Well each application has reserved storage, I want files to be manipulated as the original application intended, because as of not there is nothing stopping a malicious user from crafting a request to upload non-intended files on the applications storage space.

Comment: So only those requests to manipulate files made from the application served from the server can be executed.

Comment: That's totally impossible.

Comment: If it is impossible, do you have any suggestions as to how I might discourage or make it difficult for someone to abuse this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you send a token with every request and require the token to be returned on the next request, you will make it much more difficult for people to harm your site.

The general approach is to create a token, store it in a session variable, send it to the client, and then test for the token and value on the next request.